# Add a menu item for OS X Trash dock menu

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to add a menu item for the OS X Dock Trash icon. If you right click on it you should be able to see "Open" and "Empty Trash". I want to add another option among those. Is there any way i can do that?

If that is impossible (or at least very hard) to do then is there a way to programmatically empty the trash on OS X from Cocoa application or maybe AppleScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add menu items to any item in the Dock besides the one for your own application. The Trash icon is created internally by Dock.app.

Emptying the trash is trivial using AppleScript, though:

```
tell application "Finder" to empty trash
```